# Php form is getting submitted without submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I want to do a survey on my website for that i am designing a php form The form is looks like this.

```
<?php    
    function survey(){
?>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("intro").show();
                $("q1").hide();
                $("q2").hide();
            $("#continue").click(function(){
              $("intro").hide();
              $("q1").show();
            });
            $("#continue1").click(function(){
              $("intro").hide();
              $("q1").hide();
              $("q2").show();
            });
            $("#continue2").click(function(){
              $("q2").hide();
            });
          });
        </script>
        <intro>
          <p>Understanding of ...</p>
          <button id="continue">Continue</button>
        </intro>
        <form name="survey" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="survey">
          <q1>
            <p>[Q01]A balloon ...?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="r">(a) The internal energy of the gas decreases from its initial value, but the enthalpyremains constant<br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="w">(b) The internal energy of the gas increases from its initial value, but the enthalpyremains constant<br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="w">(c) Both internal energy and enthalpy of the gas remain constant</br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="w">(d) Both internal energy and enthalpy of the gas increase</br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="w">e) Nothing can be inferred because the system is not in equilibrium</br>
            <button id="continue1">Continue</button>
          </q1>
          <q2>
            <p>[Q02] A system is ...</p>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="w">(a) Q1 = Q2 b.  W1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="w">(b) W1 + Q1 = Q2 + W2</br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="w">(c) W1 = W2 d.  Q1</br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="r">(d) Q1 – W1 = Q2 – W2</br>
            <button id="continue2">Continue</button>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
          </q2>
        </form>
<?php
  }
?>
```

In another php page I am calling this function to display this form.

**The form is expected to work** like this when the user loads the page the  div will show and when the user is pressing continue button the  div will load it is expected to continue like this.

**But what exactly is Happening** when user press continue button from the intro the form will work as we  expected, then again user press continue button the intro will hide and the q1 will show when user again, press continue button the form is getting submitted without pressing the submit button what is wrong with this and how to solve this?.

The form should only get submitted after pressing the submit button.

Comment: Improved youre Formatting a bit and saw that youre jusing a lot of invalid HTML Tags like `<br>`

Comment: Given that this is XHTML (it looks like) yes `<br>` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<button>` without `type` declared will default to `type="submit"`. You can avoid the unexpected submittal by changing it to `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" id="continue1">Continue</button>
```

Alternatively in your click handler you can prevent the default event

```
$("#continue1").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    /* other code*/
});
```

I don't see how any of the hide/show code can work because all your jQuery selectors are invalid. They are all looking for tagnames that don't exist.

`$("q1")` would match `<q1>` tag not the elements you have in form. you should spend some time in the [selectors section of jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: <button type="button" id="continue1">Continue</button> Thank you this is what i missed.